# Get href value from matching anchor text

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm pretty new to the DOMDocument class and can't seem to find an answer for what i'm trying to do.

I have a large html file and i want to grab the link from an element based on the anchor text.

so for example

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="main">
    <a href="http://link.com" target="blank" ><span><font style="color: #e7552c;"><img src="http://images.com/spacer.gif"/>Keyword</font></span></a>
    other text
</div>
HTML;

// domdocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

i want to get the value of the href attribute of any element that has the text *keyword*. Hope that was clear

Comment: You have invalid HTML: 1 `<div>` and 2 `</div>`s

Comment: develop regular expression for your own purpose...

Comment: it was part of a larger html file, forgot to remove the extra div before posting. Change made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="main">
    <a href="http://link.com" target="blank" ><span><font style="color: #e7552c;"><img src="http://images.com/spacer.gif"/>Keyword</font></span></a>
    other text
</div>
HTML;

$keyword = "Keyword";

// domdocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$as = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($as as $a) {
    if ($a->nodeValue === $keyword) {
        echo $a->getAttribute('href'); // prints "http://link.com"
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for that ugly inner `for` loop? Why not simply `$a->getAttribute('href')`?